# Excel formula to return the value by searching "()" just before last occurrence value

Tags: excel, vba, string

I need some help in below formula for Excel

My question is
Cell value:  Ab(123)cd(1).cvs

In above cell value I just want to remove the value with brackets i.e. (1) according to the last occurrence character.

Output required: Ab(123)cd.csv

Thanks in advance.

Please help me with the above question.

Comment: What have you tried so far? [Something like this is worth a try](https://trumpexcel.com/find-characters-last-position/) (which was the first google search result btw)

Comment: Can there be a case `Ab(123)cd.cvs` - and if yes, do you expect the result to be `Abcd.cvs`? Or are you looking specifically for the brackets before the dot? And are you looking for an Excel formula or VBA?

Comment: I want Ab(123)cd(1).cvs and result should be Ab(123)cd.cvs also would like to dd one more thing. There can be 2 dots "." In the complete value , we need to look only the last occurrence character. Also one more thing

There can be 2 dots in the value like " A.b(123)cd(1).cvs "

So we only need to work on last occurrence character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple UDF to accomplish the task:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function RemoveBracketedValue(ByVal FileName As String) As String
   Dim i As Long: i = InStrRev(FileName, "(")
   Dim j As Long: j = InStrRev(FileName, ")")
   
   If i > 0 And j > 0 Then
      RemoveBracketedValue = Mid(FileName, 1, i - 1) & Mid(FileName, j + 1)
   Else
      RemoveBracketedValue = FileName
   End If
End Function
```

You would use the UDF like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank very much you,this is working as expected!

Answer (score 0):

So like this works:

[image]

Not controlled for any outlier cases like ab(123)cd.csv as you don't supply any variations so I assumed your data will always be of the form Ab(123)cd(1).csv.

Added function as text:

```
LEFT(A1,FIND("(",A1,FIND("(",A1,1)+1)-1)&RIGHT(A1,4)
```

Comment: Would be good if you would put the formula as Text into your answer. Also, you are not only assuming that there are exactly 2 opening `(`-characters but also that the suffix is always 4 characters.

Comment: @FunThomas usually I add as text - you could check my other answers if you don't believe... However I DID state clearly that the form expected was the form stated in the question.

Comment: I believe you (never doubted it, looked as if you simply forgot it). Anyhow: I think if OP gives so unsharp specifications, it's better to ask for clarification first.

Comment: Hi Solar Mike,

This formula is working for: Ab(123)cd(1).CSV

But in a different case when:

Value : Ab(123)cd(1).xlsx

Output received: Ab(123)cdxlsx

Output expected: Ab(123)cd.xlsx

Kindly provide a solution for dynamic last occurrence character.

Comment: @Xoxo so if right() is set to take the last 4 characters then you could use an if() with two versions of right() - one for 4 characters and one for 5 perhaps you should consider checking for the position of the “.” compared to the length of the string… Some good practice for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next function:

```
Function ReplaceParenthesisBeforeDot(str As String) As String
  Dim lastP As Long: lastP = InStrRev(str, ".")
  Dim strP As String, i As Long
  
  If Mid(str, lastP - 1, 1) = ")" Then
    strP = ")"
    For i = lastP - 2 To 1 Step -1
        strP = Mid(str, i, 1) & strP
        If Mid(str, i, 1) = "(" Then Exit For
    Next i
    ReplaceParenthesisBeforeDot = _
       StrReverse(VBA.Replace(StrReverse(str), StrReverse(strP), "", count:=1)) 
  End If
End Function
```

It can be tested as:

```
Sub testReplaceParenthesisBeforeDot()
  Dim str As String:  str = "Ab(123)cd(1).cvs"
  Debug.Print ReplaceParenthesisBeforeDot(str)
End Sub
```

Or call it as UDF:

```
  =ReplaceParenthesisBeforeDot(A2)
```

Where A2 is the cell where the string to be processed (remove the last parenthesis) should be placed.

Comment: The use of Replace might cause issues if the block being removed is identical to another block in the filename - e.g. `str = "Ab(123)cd(123).cvs"`

Comment: @CLR Yes, you are right... I (superficially) thought that the last part will be copies which will not exceed one digit. But the first parenthesis theoretically can also be identic. I will immediately update the answer, to delete only the last. If I remember well, `Replace` has a last parameter and using `StrReverse` I can choose the last (as first...). Thanks!

Comment: Great ita working!! Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help!

Hi Solar Mike,

This formula is working for:  Ab(123)cd(1).CSV

But in a different case when:

Case 1: Ab123cd(1).CSV

Output received: Ab123cd(1).CSV

Expected output: ab123cd.csv

Case 2
Value : Ab(123)cd(1).xlsx

Output received: Ab(123)cdxlsx

Output expected: Ab(123)cd.xlsx

Kindly provide a solution for dynamic last occurrence character.

Also one more thing

There can be 2 dots in the value like
" A.b(123)cd(1).cvs "

So we only need to work on last occurrence character.

Comment: As this is a follow-on question, not an answer, please ask a new question using the blue 'Ask Question' button , above